# LaunchControl error -- User cannot execute file

Tags: python, macos, automation, job-scheduling

I'm trying to use launchcontrol to run a python script I have over the course of a day. When I go to create a new agent, I believe I am supposed to supply the path where my script resides in the box that asks for a program to run, but when I do so the box turns from green to red and gives me an error. The path I supply to this box is:
/Users/Dave/Programming/ClassifiedsCrawlerScipt/ClassifiedsCrawler.py

The error I see says something along the lines of User Dave (501) cannot execute file: "/Users/Dave/Programming/ClassifiedsCrawlerScipt/ClassifiedsCrawler.py"

I also get Error 13 on the side panel for the status of my new agent.

I can't tell if this is a permissions related issue judging by what little I can find online, but I haven't had much luck in finding a decent tutorial for launchcontrol or anything related to this issue directly. Any links or suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The error description is very clear. User Dave cannot execute this script. To fix this open Terminal.app as user Dave and enter:

`chmod u+x /Users/Dave/Programming/ClassifiedsCrawlerScipt/ClassifiedsCrawler.py`

As for a launchd/launchctl/LaunchControl tutorial: http://launchd.info

Comment: This error can also be thrown for non-existent files-- in my case by putting, e.g., 'script.rb' instead of the intended 'script/script.rb'

Comment: @Jay: LaunchControl (which user3339984 uses) knows the difference and informs the user accordingly. launchd on Mavericks reports error 78 in both cases.

Comment: I saw that error ("User x (501) cannot execute file") on OSX 10.10.5 (Yosemite) using LaunchControl Version 1.22.3. Resolved when I input the script's proper path.

Comment: @Jay: This sounds like a bug to me. I just gave it a try and got the correct error message. If you have the time you should file a bug report.

Comment: Thanks for the follow up-- glad to hear it's supposed to be more intuitive!

Comment: Looks like you're the developer behind LaunchControl? Thank you for your work!